# Где в AndroidStudio "сохранить как"?

Tags: android-studio

Никак не могу найти в AndroidStudio "сохранить как", он там имеется?

Comment: А это вам зачем?.. Какова ваша задача? Такой кнопки там нет, да и не должно быть.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сохранить проект под новым именем, но что бы и старый не пропал.

Comment: Вы хотите добиться что то вроде branch или tag? Используйте систему управления версиями

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно лишь найти нужный вам проект в виде папки. После чего её копирнуть куда-либо и переименовать копию.

Comment: я так и дела, но думал есть с более нормальный способ как в eclipse )

Comment: @VargSieg, это и есть нормальный способ. А кнопки такой в студии нет, т.к. по хорошему, такие операции делают с помощью `git` и их механизма `веток`. Т.е. разные версии одного проекта лежат в одной папке, хоть и имеют разный код и разные названия.